# BST search key in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I was trying to implement BST search method for finding a key in BST. Below is the code.

```
node* search_key(node **root,int key)
{
    if (*root == NULL || (*root)->data == key ){
        return (*root);
    } 
    if ( key < (*root)->data ) {
         search_key(&(*root)->left, key); 
    }
    else{
         search_key(&(*root)->right, key);
    }
}
```

Above code was always returning null except for searching root node. I modified the code to the following and it is working perfectly.
Can anyone please explain the recursion involved here?

```
node* search_key(node **root,int key)
{
    if (*root == NULL || (*root)->data == key ){
        return (*root);
    } 
    if ( key < (*root)->data ) {
         return search_key(&(*root)->left, key); // note return 
    }
    else{
         return search_key(&(*root)->right, key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you're passing `node **root` instead of just `node *root`.  Using the double pointer makes the code unnecessarily unwieldy without conferring any obvious benefit.  If you were ever going to change the value that `root` points at, the double pointer would be beneficial; as it stands, I don't see any benefit and I do see some detriment (it'll be slower, all else apart, because it requires an extra level of indirection; whether that slowdown is measurable is another issue, of course).

Comment: To expand on the comment by @JonathanLeffler, even if you want to modify the pointer, if you're programming in C++ you should probably be using references instead of an extra pointer indirection. The end-result will be the same, but with nicer syntax, and also easier to understand what the function might do for casual readers (which will include you in the future).

Comment: I was just experimenting with pointers and wanted to learn pointers in depth hence i chose to use node **root by keeping root local and not making it global. I will keep in mind above suggestions while implementing something like this in production. Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 3):

In the first code snippet you have a function which is supposed to return something, but doesn't do that in some cases. That will lead to *undefined behavior*.

In the second snippet you actually return something in all paths of the function.

Comment: Most compilers will complain about the missing returns in the first code, won't they?  Ignoring compiler warnings is a bad step.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, and Clang does emit a warning even without any special flags, unfortunately GCC does not (it does with `-Wall`), I don't know about VC++.

Comment: Oh, yes; even GCC 5.3.0 doesn't warn about it without any warning options.  I so routinely compile with much more extensive warning options (`gcc -std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -c bst.c`) that I don't know which warnings are provided by default any more (and I don't think that omission from my knowledge is a major problem, either!).

Comment: compiled using g++ compiler, didn't get any warnings!

Answer (score 1):

When you call same function or another function with a function it make a call of that function and when it completed call comes back to the caller function
 here call is coming back to caller but no result as you are not returning any result.

So after returning value to the called function it starts showing correct result.

Follow this image of factorial function for better understanding[image]

Answer (score 0):

While implementing recursion we should *always make sure that for each condition when we call the function recursively, then there should be a "return" statement* so that immediate caller of a function will get the resultant value and therefore at the end of the recursion final value will be returned.

**What in case if return statement is not used:**

If there is no return statement, then the value computed by the current function will be discarded or unsaved so that the immediate caller won't get any value and further it will end up with undefined behaviour.

Comment: There needs to be at least one base case where you don't call the function recursively.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you are right!!  but still in that case also a "return" statement is required right?? if not how the caller in the main function will get the final value.

Comment: Yes, even the base case needs to return a value.  The 'problem' I see is my interpretation of your phrase _always make sure that for each condition we are using the function_.  If that means _for each condition, the code must call the function_, then it is wrong because of the base case that is needed to terminate the recursion — the base case usually won't call the function again.  If you mean _for each condition where the function is called recursively, there should be a return statement_ then you'd be correct.  I apologize; this is a subtle issue in the use of English.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler- sorry..typo error in my comment..Thanks for correcting my grammar :)

Answer (score 0):

In the binary tree there are 2 roots the left and  right root. So your first condition says if you are in the last node (where root == NULL) or you find the key (value on root->data match the value of key) so, the program returns the exact block that contain the data (there it is not recursive).

```
if (*root == NULL || (*root)->data == key ){
    return (*root);
```

The second condition say if the key is less than the value stored into `root->data`, the node go to the left root. So, the line `return`search_key(root->left,key)` means: redo the same operation but now go to the left root.

```
if ( key < (*root)->data ) {
     return search_key(&(*root)->left, key);
}
```

So, let's imagine that in the left root, the `root->data` is higher than the key,
so the line `return search_key(root->right,key)` means redo this operation but now go to the right root.

```
else{
     return search_key(&(*root)->right, key);
}
```

The recursion will end only if you find the key somewhere or you check everything and you did not find anything. So remember, recursion means redo it again and again.

Comment: I think you need to work on the first sentence: _In the binary tree there are 2 roots the left and right root._  A binary tree has a single root, but each node in a binary tree can have up to two child nodes, the left node and the right node.  (When you have two roots, you have a forest, not just a single tree.)